# Right to left text is displayed reversed in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, arabic, right-to-left

I am using the following version of eclipse

**Version:** 2021-09 (4.21.0)

**Build id:** 20210910-1417

and I have bidirectional text is enabled in my workspace as follows :

**Window > Preferences > General > Globalization > Enable bidirectional support**

Graphical layout direction (OS Default)

Text direction (OS Default)

Issue: when trying to type

تقييم الموظف من قبل المدير المباشر

it appears in eclipse as follows

المباشر المدير قبل من الموظف تقييم

Comment: In which editor? Did you checked [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/)? Make sure it has been reported, best with a patch.

Comment: all editors java,text,html

Comment: you are right, it is already reported here : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=571642

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in the _Text Editor_ when running Eclipse with the arguments `-dir rtl -bidi "on=y;textDir=rtl"`. Please note, Java is by default left-to-right.

Comment: @howlger I don’t think it’s an issue with Java’s defaults.  I pasted the text into an English Swing application (using Java 17) and an English JavaFX 17 application, and both pasted correctly.

Comment: @VGR Right-to-left for a whole text file is a different thing than mixing left-to-right and right-to-left in an UTF-8 text file. The first works for me in Eclipse. When I remember correctly, [right-to-left mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) support is missing for the second (bidirectional is done character-bassed leading to have right-to-left in a word but the words are displayed left-to-right).

Comment: @howlger An explicit RTL mark should not be needed.  My understanding of the bidi algorithm is that the direction is set by a character’s Unicode bidi properties.  Spaces are bidi-neutral and should not alter the direction, which in fact is the behavior I am seeing in Swing and JavaFX.

Comment: @VGR Feel free to propose a patch.

Comment: Any ideas if the issue has been fixed ? @howlger

Comment: Please link to the bug, not to the one you mentioned (that's not the right one), but to the one of what @VGR [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70169147/right-to-left-text-is-displayed-reversed-in-eclipse?noredirect=1#comment124043759_70169147).